# Logging Amazon SES Message ID

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

This might be a simple question but I've searched and searched and can't find an answer.

I'd like to log the message ID for each email sent so I can more accurately do bounce handling.

I'm using the AWS PHP SDK to send my emails. How can I get the message ID after I send an email?

Comment: I think it's impossible, but U can set message-id manually and store before send

Comment: Found the answer...

I'm able to retrieve the MessageID from the response object I get upon sending an email with SES.

<code>$response->body->SendEmailResult->MessageId</code>

Comment: If you think your own answer is the best answer here, please check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer...

I'm able to retrieve the MessageID from the response object I get upon sending an email with SES.

`$response->body->SendEmailResult->MessageId`

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer:
sendEmail returns a [Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_sendEmail).

You can get the value of MessageId with `$response->get('MessageId')`

More info: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-models.html

Comment: This is now the best answer especially with version 3 of the SDK

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SES change Message-ID, see first comment

Comment: AWS changes the Message-Id when you send.

The following headers can/will be modified:

    Message-Id
    Date
    Return-Path
    Bounces-To

Currently Amazon SES sets the Message-Id so as to be able to correlate sent emails with feedback like bounces and complaints. Using the Message-Id header ensures that Amazon SES can identify the original send request, in turn ensures that Amazon SES can identify you as the original sender and forward the bounce on to you.

I suppose I could add my own Message-Id which AWS will forward on but that seems like a waste when AWS have already done it.

Comment: @MattClements Set your own custom header like : MyHeaderId: <YourID>, I set my own header for detect bounced message.

Comment: @MattClements I have a project with mass email sends, and will use amazon at next week. If U found solution, please, update Ur post

Comment: Source for first comment is https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=262855. List of all SES headers with notes on those that get overridden:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-fields.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the response from amazon into a variable and then parse the xml;

```
$res = $this->amazon_ses->send();
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($res);
$email_id = (string) $xml->SendEmailResult[0]->MessageId;
```

This worked well for me